# How to embed html code inside div?

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using Bootstrap. I have a table, where I saved some html code. When I try to show it inside a div, the content is showing as text and it isn't embed inside, my code is this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <p>{{$content->content}}</p>
</div>
```

Then it show this:

```
<p>code-code-code</p>
```

What should I do? I've used materialize and this problem doesn't happen.

Comment: Don't escape the content?

Comment: hi dave, no, the code is show as text, with the tags

Comment: Right. It's escaped. Don't. I'm sure there's a way to do that in your framework (noting that if it's user-entered content it's a security risk unless you're white- or black-listing tags.

Comment: That's how you do it with blade templating engine: `{!! $content->content !!}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use {!! you code !!} {{ this will echo all of your code as simple text  }}

Displaying Unescaped Data
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade